# What is the best way to compile a Rust project on-the-fly with another Rust program?

Tags: rust, compilation, compiler-construction

I am exploring the idea of using Rust to dynamically compile a program with specific changes to the source code based on each user’s needs.

My idea was to have the “compiler” program load the main.rs source file for the project it’s going to compile. It uses string replacement to make the necessary changes, and saves the file.

Next I would just like to build the project (from another Rust program) and be able to grab the resulting target file.

Of course, I could probably just use `std::process::Command`, but is there a better method rather than manually invoking “cargo build” and then waiting an arbitrary amount of seconds for the exe to be ready? With all of the online rust compilers and stuff, i figured there is a better way.

Comment: This sounds like a troublesome approach, and possibly an XY question. What kind of "specific changes" are we talking about? Can't you just create one executable whose behaviour is controlled at runtime through e.g. a configuration file, command line arguments, or environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

There is no library with public API for the compiler at the moment.

You can check that the playground uses `cargo` as a command line tool: https://github.com/integer32llc/rust-playground/blob/806ce3ec134214356e93d8df751834f1eadc0d84/ui/src/sandbox.rs#L150

> just use `std::process::Command`, but is there a better method rather than manually invoking “cargo build” and then waiting an arbitrary amount of seconds for the exe to be ready

You wouldn't need to wait an arbitrary amount of time. The command can be [awaited](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) and when it completes, either the program compiles successfully and the file as been created, or it had an error, and the result code of the compiler is non-null.